# How to change the color of an input made by a user in python

Tags: python

So im trying to make a script using Lexing and Parsing. I wanted to try and change the color of the texts when a user inputs something.

Say in python when I do:
'''print("Hello")'''
It changes the color of print, string, parens, etc. I just wanted to know how to do it
and/or the code to do it.

Say if my user types:
'''hello NAME'''
It will change the color of "hello" to green or something. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using colorama, or termcolor in python:

Here is a link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).